# "ethereumjs-util" equivalent code in python "eth-utils"

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum

```js
let message = {id : 1, metadata : "abc"}
let signature = <signature>
let nonce = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + JSON.stringify(message).length + JSON.stringify(message)
nonce = util.keccak(Buffer.from(nonce, "utf-8"))
const { v, r, s } = util.fromRpcSig(signature)
const pubKey = util.ecrecover(util.toBuffer(nonce), v, r, s)
const addrBuf = util.pubToAddress(pubKey)
const addr = util.bufferToHex(addrBuf)
```

Hello guys, I am using python "eth-utils" to replicate the code displayed above, however I have no idea how to do it, first, the formatting of `JSON.stringify()` in javascript might be different from python `json.dumps()` one, I am wondering if there are equivalent functions in "eth-utils" to `keccak()`, `fromRpcSig()`, `erecover()` and `pubToAddress()` in the javascript version. If there are no such functions, are there some ways to accomplish the same things?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution which utilizes [eth_account](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html) package in python:

```
message_hash = eth_account.messages.encode_defunct(text=json.dumps(messageSession, separators=(',', ':')))
recoveredAddress = eth_account.Account.recover_message(message_hash, signature=signature)
```

and It does the exact same thing as mentioned in the question